# Удаление разом всех писем Вконтакте

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Я вчера пытался автоматически удалить 16 000 сообщений, я осознал, что небезопасно хранить всю историю переписки. Для этого я даже нашел где-то скрипт, который был основан на циклах и if'ах (так как на одной странице - 20 сообщений - таймаут и повтор скрипта). Так вот, покрутив туда-сюда скрипт, понял, что он устарел, казалось, что я нашел, что в нем нужно обновить: вместо `delMsg(i,0)` написать `mail.deleteMsg(i,0)`, но в результате скрипт возвращал false, это в лучшем случае, а в противном - `undefined || object` тра ла ла...
Так вот, я видел часто и везде вашу рекламу, теперь думаю стоит проверить, правда ли вы спецы в своем деле, спасибо.

**Добавлено.**

Ну, если сайт не заэкранирует тут все, то вот скрипт:

```
k = 0;
MAX = 100000;

function Step() {
    for (i = MAX; i > 0; i--) {
        if (k < 20) {
            if (ge('mb' + i) != null) {
                delMsg(i, 2);
                k++;
            }
        }
        if (k == 19) {
            k++MAX = i;
            setTimeout("UpdatePage()", 3000);
            setTimeout("nextStep()", 5000);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function UpdatePage() {
    updateMessages(0);
}

function nextStep() {
    k = 0;
    Step();

}
Step();
```

где значению Max было присвоено число имеющихся писем, `delMsg(i,2)` был поочередно заменен на `deleteMsg(i, 0)` и `mail.deleteMsg(i, 0)`. Но тем не менее результатов - 0.

Comment: В каком это, своем, деле? Покажите скрипт, скажите, где возникает проблема.

Comment: Ясно, пойду ка я на другой форум)))

Comment: >  Так вот, я видел часто и везде вашу рекламу, теперь думаю стоит проверить, правда ли вы спецы в своем деле, спасибо

Ahaha, oh wow!

Comment: >теперь думаю стоит проверить, правда ли вы спецы в своем деле
С чего вы решили, что кто-то вам должен что-то доказывать. Любой уважающий себя человек, после таких слов, вас просто пошлет подальше. "На другой форум..."

Comment: Нда, улыбнуло, тяжело же вам будет на любом другом форуме) Да и по жизни с такими понятиями.

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю Ваше непонимание, но за сутки я встретил 10-15 рекламных блоков - контекстных и баннерных, вечером чистил почту ВК, к этому времени реклама уже приелась...
Если я кого то обидел, прошу прощения. И не смотря на то что вопрос с почтой решен, то вопрос со скриптом актуален, и не только мне, а очень многим пользователям сети, и поверьте мне, пока еще ни на одном ресурсе нет решения поставленной задачи. В данном случае Вы поможете в первую очередь Всем пользователям, и многим программистам будет интересно как это реализуется.

Comment: У вконтакта механизмы меняются раз в месяц. Через 2-3 месяца даже самый "учитывающий все" скрипт будет бесполезен. В общем виде механизм букмарклетов можно найти в гугле, а ваш вопрос _бесполезен_. Тем более с хтмл5 - тут уже была "отправка в цикле", итерация обрывается на смене адреса и этот скрипт уже приходится пускать в ифрейме, с подменой document.domain и еще кучей извращений. Ответ вам: ставим фаербаг, удаляем письмо, анализием запросы, пишем скрипт. Вам уже сказали, что вопрос неоправданно пафосный, он еще и бесполезный.

Comment: ЗЫ: я удалял страницу - чистил все полностью. Ни один из выложенных в инете скриптов давностью около месяца не работал, все писал сам и полдня на это убил. Увольте-с, больше не хочу)

Comment: На счет не безопасно - вы-то удалите свои сообщения, что бы они вам не выводились. Вот только из базы данных вконтакта их никто удалять не собирается. Разве что от своей девушки себя убережете, если накопает чего, пока вы в душе.

Comment: Да, где то слышал что фото не удаляют для уменьшения фрагментации, видимо с "личками" схожая трабла..

Answer (score 1):

Не советую использовать для удаления сообщений такого рода скрипты - придется подстраиваться под каждое незначительное изменение.

У вконтакте есть [оф. API](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php#devstep2), содержащий [необходимые методы](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php?o=-1&p=%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5+%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b+API) для работы с сообщениями.

Вопрос лишь в том, насколько это будет эффективно при таком количестве сообщений